# Where does mpdf print ImageErrors (when $mpdf->showImageErrors = true)?

Tags: php, mpdf

As for the title: I'm using mpdf to generate pdfs, and trying to debug broken images over https, and would like to have some hint from the program.

I setted `$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;` but can't see output anywhere. Where should I look for it?

Comment: did you check your php error log?

Comment: No I didn't, and that's right, it's there, thank you

Answer (score 1):

When `$mpdf->showImageErrors` is set to `true`, an exception is thrown. You can see the exception in your output when `display_errors` is enabled, or, as mentioned, you will see the details of the exception in a corresponding PHP error log.

By default, with `$mpdf->showImageErrors = false`, only internal logging will note an error. See the [documentation about internal PSR logging](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/logging.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: into the php error log.

Comment: Orel, this is an answer to my very question. It's exactly what I needed to now.